# В чем разница между «Угрозой ИБ» и «Риском ИБ»?

Tags: безопасность

В чем разница между «Угрозой ИБ» и «Риском ИБ»? Пожалуйста, приведите примеры и описания использования понятий на примере конкретных организаций.

Answer (score 1):

Угроза - возможное событие которое повличет проблемы
Риск - возможность ущерба с определенной "ценой" и примерным шансом появления ущерба.
Примеров с корпорациями не знаю, но интуитивный пример - ддос атака:
1) ДДОС как раз и является угрозой
2) Шанс ддоса той или иной сети, на сколько она отключится при определенных нагрузках, сколько денег при этом потеряется.
Это так, пример "на пальцах".
Как пример, можете предположить недавнюю атаку с помощью "интернета вещей".